# using strings in c++ and cygwin

Tags: c++, string, char, cin

im new at this so i need a little help.
i want to allow the input to be as many characters and spaces as neccesary to fill the input,
 for example, i typed cin>>name and cin>>birthday
if the person types their first and last name then it will skip the next cin function. how do i avoid this, i want to be able to just declare name as some sort of string or char without having to go through the whole name=first+last ordeal and having them input first and last..if someone gets what im saying i just need the header file and proper declarations..im new at this but im sure ill understand the complex answers i might get

Comment: You can use `getline` for this purpose, though it will require some parsing if they put their name and birthday on the same line.

Answer (score 2):

Use std::getline to get input on one line.

```
std::string name;
std::getline(std::cin, name);
```

Alternatively, if you expect the birthday to be on the same line, then do this.

```
std::string input;
std::getline(std::cin, input);
std::istringstream input_stream(input);
std::string first_name, last_name, birthday;
if (!(input_stream >> first_name)) std::cout << "Input cannot be empty.\n";
if (!(input_stream >> last_name)) std::cout << "You must have a last name.\n";
if (!(input_stream >> birthday)) std::cout << "You forgot your birthday.\n";
```

If the birthday contains spaces in it, then you can use std::getline on the remaining words in the stream.

```
std::getline(input_stream, birthday);
```

So finally your program becomes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::string input;
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    std::istringstream input_stream(input);
    std::string first_name, last_name, birthday;
    if (!(input_stream >> first_name)) std::cout << "Input cannot be empty.\n";
    if (!(input_stream >> last_name)) std::cout << "You must have a last name.\n";
    input_stream.ignore(); // Discard space that doesn't get extracted out
    std::getline(input_stream, birthday);
    std::cout << first_name << "\n";
    std::cout << last_name << "\n";
    std::cout << birthday;
}
```

In order to discard the space that's left in the stream, use `input_stream.ignore();`.

If you want to handle names that have spaces in it, apply the same principle. This time you have to supply arguments to ignore to tell it to discard spaces.

```
int main()
{
    std::string input;
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    std::istringstream input_stream(input);
    std::string first_name, last_name, birthday;
    std::getline(input_stream, first_name, ',');
    input_stream.ignore(1, ' '); // Discard space
    std::getline(input_stream, last_name, ',');
    input_stream.ignore(1, ' '); // Discard space
    std::getline(input_stream, birthday, ',');
    std::cout << first_name << "\n";
    std::cout << last_name << "\n";
    std::cout << birthday;
}
```

Example run:

```
First Name, Last Name, This is a birthday
First Name
Last Name
This is a birthday
```

Comment: what header file or directive do i need for the input_stream

Comment: ok so my next question is, now that i caught on a little bit to the new stuff i just read,  if i just wanted to be able to declare a string, like "string name; " i could use std::string name; " and that would allow the person that i let test my program out to type their first and last name, without getting in the way of any other inputs that follow

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to split a string by spaces. The following program uses a vector to store the elements. Check the size of it, and if it is 3, then assume the first and last name have been given.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
        std::string buffer;
        std::getline(std::cin, buffer);

        std::vector<std::string> v;
        std::string tmp;

        for(unsigned i = 0; i < buffer.length(); i++) {
                tmp += buffer[i];
                if(buffer[i] == ' ') {
                        v.push_back(tmp);
                        tmp = "";
                }
        }
        // push the last one
        v.push_back(tmp);
        copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));

        return 0;
}
```

**Compiling & Testing**

`g++ -Wall -Wextra main.cc -o main`

**Test Data**
This file is called test.txt

```
FIRST LAST 10242014
```

**To Test**
execute this: main < test.txt

**Expected Output**

```
FIRST 
LAST 
10242014
```

Answer (score 0):

I would always use `std::getline()`. I know you asked for all names on one line but I would always split the name gathering to separate lines because first, second and last names can all contain spaces (eg, Du Vall).

```
struct person
{
    std::string f_name;
    std::string m_name;
    std::string l_name;
    std::string DOB;
};

person p;

std::cout << "First name: ";
std::getline(std::cin, p.f_name);

std::cout << "Middle name(s): ";
std::getline(std::cin, p.m_name);

std::cout << "Last name: ";
std::getline(std::cin, p.l_name);

std::cout << "Date Of Birth: ";
std::getline(std::cin, p.DOB);
```